# Integrate Lync with Android

Tags: android, sip, lync-2013

```
initiateSkypeUri(context, "skype:"+ skypeID+"?call&video=true");

    public void initiateSkypeUri(Context myContext, String mySkypeUri) {
    // Make sure the Skype for Android client is installed
    if (!isInstalled(myContext, "com.skype.raider")) {
        goToMarket(myContext, "com.skype.raider");
        return;
    }
    // Create the Intent from our Skype URI
    Uri skypeUri = Uri.parse(mySkypeUri);
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, skypeUri);

    // Restrict the Intent to being handled by the Skype for Android client
    // only
    myIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.skype.raider",
            "com.skype.raider.Main"));
    myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);       
    myContext.startActivity(myIntent);

    return;
}
```

This is what i did for making call using Skype. I need to do same thing in [Lync 2013](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.microsoft.office.lync15&hl=en). How can i achieve this?

Thanks in advance.